Compilation errors specific to my version of pulled code that builds for others - dynamic fields in constructors and unable to infer types
I was tasked with working on a branch with a co-worker, but when I pulled their code, the branch would not build for me. We asked other developers to pull the code and see if their branches built, and it worked for everyone except me. One of the weird things is - there were more errors than I am currently getting, but after my co-worked pushed a commit (that didn't touch the files in question) some of the errors went away.
I'd like to verify that I am receiving these errors inaccurately, and then get some help figuring out what I can do to resolve them.
We're using .NET 6, but I ran into the same issues when trying to .NET 8.
The code with the compilation errors (I've added comments in the places where the errors appear):
public class DisplayColumn : Column<dynamic?, object>
{
    private DisplayColumn(ColumnId id, dynamic? value, object attributes) 
        : base(id, value, attributes) { } // One of the errors is shown here: CS1975

    public static class DisplayColumnFactory
    {
        public static DisplayColumn Create(Guid columnId, dynamic? value, object attribute)
        {
            var displayColumn = new DisplayColumn(
                new(columnId), // The other error is shown here: CS8754
                value, 
                attribute);

            return displayColumn;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class GuidBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    protected GuidBase(Guid guid)
    {
        if (guid == Guid.Empty)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Id value cannot be empty!");
        }

        Id = guid;
    }
}

public class ColumnId : GuidBase
{
    public ColumnId(Guid guid) : base(guid)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class Column<TValue, TAttribute>
{
    public ColumnId Id { get; }
    public TValue Value { get; }
    public TAttribute Attributes { get; }

    protected Column(ColumnId id, TValue value, TAttribute attributes)
    {
        Id = id;
        Value = value;
        Attributes = attributes;
    }
}

Here are the errors I'm getting:

This error is that it can't pass a dynamic value from the constructor for DisplayColumn to the base Column class, despite the fact that Column takes an argument of dynamic Picture of Error
This error is that it can't find infer the constructor used (Picture of Error). It infers it fine in other classes AND infers it fine in Visual Studio's auto-complete (Visual Studio showing that it can infer the type).

I've tried:

Deleting and re-pulling the code base
Updating Visual Studio
Completely uninstalling and re-installing Visual Studio
Upgrading to .NET 8
Running dotnet build on the project without Visual Studio

But nothing gets rid of these errors. Help would be greatly appreciated.

In the constructor, you can try to explicitly cast the dynamic type parameter to object or another specific type, so that the compiler knows the exact type to use during construction: (object)value. When calling the constructor, make sure to specify the target type. You can try directly creating a ColumnId instance instead of using implicit types: new ColumnId(columnId). Or you can try cleaning and rebuilding the project, and make sure your development environment matches that of other developers. Sometimes different SDK versions can lead to compilation errors.

@YumiaoKong I appreciate the suggestion, but I am trying to figure out why the errors are happening for me and only me. I can solve these issues on their own, but if I don't understand why .NET says these errors are here, then I don't know how to prevent having more of them in the future.

Maybe you can try to compare your project files (.csproj) and solution files (.sln) with your colleagues to ensure no settings are overlooked, and try to clean and rebuild the solution.

That's a good suggestion, and also one of the first things we did (I guess I didn't list it in the things we tried, sorry). Those files are part of our version control (git) and we made sure there wasn't anything different about them. Cleaning and rebuilding happened often, along with removing the .bin and .obj file folders manually, just in case.
